# IN Flutter Web getting 'XMLHttpRequest' error while making WCF https call

Tags: c#, flutter, wcf, xmlhttprequest, flutter-web

WCF Services working in postman and in flutter web
and test cors origin too in
https://www.test-cors.org/#?client_method=POST&client_credentials=false&server_url=https%3A%2F%2Fvdent.co%2FVDentPatientRestWs.svc%2Flogin&server_enable=true&server_status=200&server_credentials=false&server_tabs=remote
and ajax call
in https://resttesttest.com/
all working right and back status 200
but with flutter web ... back xmlhttprequest

Comment: Are you getting back any response?  If you are not getting back anything then it is probably a TLS issue which is performed before the request to get secure authentication.  If you are getting back a response then usually it is a default HTTP header that is different between c# and Postman.

Comment: Is there any detailed error message? You can refer to "Tracing and Message Logging": https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/framework/wcf/samples/tracing-and-message-logging

Answer (score 0):

You can try to give headers for your webview.

```
   WebView(

               gestureNavigationEnabled: true,

               key: _key,
            
              debuggingEnabled: true,

               javascriptMode: JavascriptMode.unrestricted,


           onWebViewCreated: (WebViewController webViewController) {

             webControl=webViewController;

             _controller.complete(webViewController);

             Map<String, String> header = {'my-header': 'is-this'};
    
             webControl.loadUrl("yourURL",headers: header);

               },
)
```

(You should create webControl and _controller variables)